# How many different (full/complete) in-order binary-trees do exist?

Tags: binary-trees, binary-search-trees

Given be a binary tree whose elements printed in-order results in `[1,2,3,4]`.
**Q1:** How many different binary-trees do exist?
**Q2:** How many different **complete** binary-trees do exist?
**Q3:** How many different **full** binary-trees do exist?

For Q1 I was able to find a solution, by using the catalan number formula:
`c(n) = (2n)! / ((n + 1)! * n!)` → `c(4) = 14`.

For Q2 and Q3 however I was not able to find an answer to those problems.
Do general formulas for `n` elements even exist?

[Definition of full and complete.](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs3114/Fall09/wmcquain/Notes/T03a.BinaryTreeTheorems.pdf)

Comment: There is exactly one complete binary tree with any given number of leaves.

Comment: Full binary trees are also enumerated by Catalan numbers (with a shift).

Comment: (Note that stackexchange encourages answering your own question. Consider using a "spoiler".)

Answer (score 1):

**Q1:** How many different binary-trees do exist?
**A1:** `c(n) = (2n)! / ((n + 1)! * n!)` → `c(4) = 14`

**Q2:** How many different complete binary-trees do exist?
**A2:** Exact one:

```
;       (3)        L0: full
;      / | \
;   (2)  |  (4)    L1: full
;   /|   |   |
; (1)|   |   |     L2: not full (Node 2 is missing right child)
;  | |   |   |
;  1 2   3   4     Complete?: Yes, because all (but last) levels are full.
```

**Q3:** How many different full binary-trees do exist?
**A3:** If `n` is odd: `c((n-1)/2)` else `0`. `n = 4` therefore `0`. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54498211/8392919)

Thanks to [YuvalFilmus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/683/yuval-filmus) for the help!